# how to add click event on caurousalview in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms

i want to  add click event on caurousal view in xamarin form just like listviewitemclick event 
i tried for Gesture-recognizer but its not working.

```
                       <CarouselView   Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding UpcomingDatas}"   
                            Position="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}"   >                               
                            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate >
                                    <DataTemplate>

                                    <material:MaterialCard BorderColor="LightGray" BindingContext="{Binding DoctorName}"  Padding="1" CornerRadius="12" Elevation="8" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <material:MaterialCard.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                                        </material:MaterialCard.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Grid>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />

                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />

                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"  Grid.RowSpan="2" >
                                                <Frame CornerRadius="5" Padding="0" IsClippedToBounds="True">
                                                    <Image  Source="ic_temp" />
                                                </Frame>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="5"  Text="{Binding MedicalCentreName}" FontFamily="{StaticResource Gilroy-Medium}"  TextColor="#4D4D4D" FontSize="20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
                                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  FontFamily="{StaticResource Gilroy-Medium}"  WidthRequest="30" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  TextColor="{StaticResource ColorNavy}">
                                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                                        <FormattedString>
                                                            <Span Text="{Binding Date}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="{StaticResource Gilroy-Medium}"/>
                                                            <Span Text="{Binding Month}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="{StaticResource Gilroy-Medium}" />
                                                        </FormattedString>
                                                    </Label.FormattedText>
                                                </Label>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  WidthRequest="70" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="{StaticResource ColorNavy}">
                                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                                        <FormattedString>
                                                            <Span Text="{Binding Time}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="{StaticResource Gilroy-Medium}"/>
                                                            <Span Text="{Binding Day}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="{StaticResource Gilroy-Medium}" />
                                                        </FormattedString>
                                                    </Label.FormattedText>
                                                </Label>                                                                                                       
                                           </StackLayout>                                                                                                   
                                            </Grid>
                                        </material:MaterialCard>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>                                
                            </CarouselView>
                            <local:CarouselIndicators Grid.Row="2" IndicatorHeight="8" Padding="10" IndicatorWidth="8" UnselectedIndicator="unselected_circle.png" SelectedIndicator="selected_circle.png" Position="{Binding Position}"  ItemsSource="{Binding UpcomingDatas}" />
```

i tried with adding gesture recognizer on card but its not working
can anyone guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the [CurrentItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/interaction) and then play with the [CurrentItemChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/interaction) event

To handle the click, you can use the event handler or a command. 
For event handler:

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding UpcomingDatas}" 
          CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentUpcomingData}"
          CurrentItemChanged="OnCurrentUpcomingDataChanged">
...
```

For a command:

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding UpcomingDatas}" 
          CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentUpcomingData}" 
          CurrentItemChangedCommand="{Binding UpcomingDataItemChangedCommand}"
          CurrentItemChangedCommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=CurrentUpcomingData}">
...
```

For more details, see the section [Respond to the current item changing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/interaction#respond-to-the-current-item-changing).

Comment: thanks for answering my question,but can u help me with  how to add click event on caurousallview?

Comment: I edited my anwser showing how to handle the click event.